# Prove that F(z)=$\int_{\mathbb R}\exp(-\pi(u+z)^2)$ is analytic

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Prove that F(z)=$\int_{\mathbb R}\exp(-\pi(u+z)^2)$ is analytic

I want to prove that $F(z)=1$ for every $z \in \mathbb C$ using that $F(z)=1$ for every $z \in \mathbb R$

At first I thought that this problem is trivial since $\exp()$ is analytic and the integral converges for every $z \in \mathbb C$. Is that enough to conclude that $F$ is analytic ?

Would appreciate any help/hints

Comment: You could also apply Morera's theorem. (You will also need Fubini's theorem in that case to interchange the order of integration).

Comment: You could prove $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-\pi u^2)\cos(2\pi u y) du = \exp(-\pi y^2)$, which would directly establish $F(z) = 1$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$. But that's less trivial.